# How would it be advised to get Immutables to build this object with this sort

Tags: java, immutables-library

How could I get Immutables to generate a class with this sort

```
public class IdentifiedUserDetails implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer, Identified<UUID> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4905378177558522349L;

    private final UUID id;
    private final String username;
    private final Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    private boolean accountNonLocked = true;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    private boolean enabled = true;
    private String password;

    IdentifiedUserDetails( final UUID id, final String username, final String password ) {
        this.id = Objects.requireNonNull( id );
        this.username = Objects.requireNonNull( username );
        this.password = Objects.requireNonNull( password );
        this.authorities = Collections.unmodifiableSet( sortAuthorities( Collections.emptySet() ) );
    }

    private static SortedSet<GrantedAuthority> sortAuthorities(
        final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities ) {
        // Ensure array iteration order is predictable (as per
        // UserDetails.getAuthorities() contract and SEC-717)
        return authorities.stream()
            .filter( Objects::nonNull )
            .collect( Collectors.toCollection( () -> {
                return new TreeSet<GrantedAuthority>(
                    Comparator.nullsFirst( Comparator.comparing( GrantedAuthority::getAuthority ) ) );
            } ) );
    }
}
```

note: the empty set is a placeholder for a real set passed in from some external data source, I haven't started populating it yet but I will at some point, and the sort is a re-implementation of the one in spring security, you should presume that the sort needs to be applied to any set that would be passed to the Immutables builder.

Comment: Your question is unclear...

Comment: @assylias how is it unclear? what do you not understand?

Comment: It is really not clear what you want to achieve with your code; and where you perceived problem is!

Comment: Oh, just realised that "immutables" is a library - I thought you were referring to immutable objects and your question made little sense.

Comment: yes it's a library :D, and I've seen how to use collections, but I don't see how I could apply a sort with that. Since I tagged it I didn't think I'd have to explain that bit.

Comment: You want to get sortable (or sorted) set after `Collections.unmodifiableSet` function call?

Comment: @degr that's my understanding of this code which I have basically reimplemented: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java#L116

Comment: step by step `1.`sortAuthorities( Collections.emptySet() (or your authorities)) you are getting SortedSet object `2.`  Collections.unmodifiableSet(prevResult) you are getting <something> that implement `Set` interface. Probably, it can be sorted, but I absolutely sure, that it will not (due performance reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many variations on how you can achieve that using Immutables annotation processor, given that I understand what you trying to achieve ;)

Immutables supports `SortedSet` out of the box, but only using natural ordering (see `@Value.NaturalOrder` and `@Value.ReverseOrder`). If you want to apply special comparator, Immutables will only allow you to build the set yourself and set it onto a builder. Judging from the example, it is desirable that ordering would be something specific to the implementation of the object, so I'll skip to other options.

There's powerful (but somewhat error-prone) functionality to enable normalization/canonicalization of the object using `@Value.Check` method. It is described in the guide: http://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#normalization. However, using the normalization is a bit complicated by the need to check if a set/collection is already sorted.

In the end, I would propose yet another, simpler approach, which I've used for similar purposes. `@Value.Derived` annotation allows you to build an alternative view of a data during object construction. In this case there will be collection used as initialization buffer and the computed, alternative view of this data. Computation will happen during construction and an immutable object will never change after that. We'll play with access and attribute names to make it look nice. Here's the example:

```
@Value.Immutable
public abstract class IdentifiedUserDetails implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer, Identified<UUID> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4905378177558522349L;

    public abstract UUID getId();
    public abstract String getUsername();
    public abstract String getPassword();
    // other attributes omitted for brevity
    // ...

    abstract @SkipNulls List<GrantedAuthority> authority();

    @Value.Derived
    public SortedSet<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authority().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> {
                    return new TreeSet(
                            Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)));
                }));
    }
}

public static void demonstration(GrantedAuthority ga1, GrantedAuthority ga2) {

    IdentifiedUserDetails details =
            ImmutableIdentifiedUserDetails.builder()
                    .id(UUID.randomUUID())
                    .username("Name")
                    .password("String")
                    //...
                    .addAuthority(ga1)
                    .addAuthority(ga2)
                    .build();

    SortedSet<GrantedAuthority> sortedAuthorities = details.getAuthorities();
}
```

P.S. `@SkipNulls` is a kind of BYOAnnotation. Create it, if needed, and it will be recognized by a simple name.